# How can I emulate RaspberryPi on Ubuntu?

Tags: raspberrypi, emulation

I was looking to virtually emulate Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu 12.04.

I saw some articles like [HOWTO: Virtual Raspbian on Qemu in Ubuntu Linux 12.10](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=37386)

In this tutorial there is a field `-append /dev/sda2`, but I don't know whether it's the virtual field or my real disk... I don't want to risk losing my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `/dev/sda2` is the parameter specifying which device to mount as the root filesystem.

I followed [this guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20131210001407/http://xecdesign.com/working-with-qemu/).